# Crear una clase para un modelo 3D

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo un modelo de datos, en principio en `Java`, pero que sea válido para cualquier lenguaje, para que todo el mundo use las mismas clases y atributos. Es una especie de DTO. Dentro de este modelo de datos necesito representar/usar `modelos 3D` (de un edificio, por ejemplo). Necesito crear una clase en la que uno de sus atributos sea un objeto en 3D, o crear una clase que represente a ese modelo en 3D.

Ando un poco perdido en cuanto al 3D y no se como modelizarlo. Se que necesito representar coordenadas, el nombre del modelo y un identificador único. Pero no se si la aproximación es correcta. No se si simplemente tengo que usar el paquete Java3D importando alguna clase en especial o si eso está anticuado.

¿Podéis ayudarme?

Comment: no entiendo bien su pregunta, igual puede tratar de aclararla un poco, pero puede echarle un vistazo a esto -> https://www.lwjgl.org/ a ver si es lo que busca aunque igual es mucho para lo que quiere hacer, puede mirar aqui -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VS8wlS9hF8E&list=PLRIWtICgwaX0u7Rf9zkZhLoLuZVfUksDP. Saludos

Comment: Hola Angel, lo que intento es generar un DTO (https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objeto_de_Transferencia_de_Datos_(DTO)) en el que se pueda representar, además de otras cosas, un modelo en 3D

Comment: si entiendo bien, lo que usted quiere hacer es obtener unos datos, y estos datos son los objetos 3D, me refiero a su estructura por ejemplo si fuera .obj .blend el que sea y despues de recivir esos datos su programa es el que se encarga de mostrarlos al usuario mediante openGL por ejemplo

Comment: tambien creo que podria usar LibGDX para mostar el modelo por pantalla pues cuenta con librerias y funciones para el manejo de modelos 3D https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx , usa de backend lwjgl el link que te deje al principio, en el repo lo puede ver en https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/tree/master/backends

Comment: Si, o mediante vuforia o cualquier otro framework de RA.

Comment: pero tampoco se muy bien lo que quieres hacer e igual esta es una forma mas complicada de hacer lo que quieres, yo me estoy imaginando que cuentas con algo asi como un form con botones, y dentro de ese form igual puede crear un contexto openGL con LibGDX y mostrar el modelo 3D, pues cuenta con metodos y librerias para parsear/importar objetos 3D dentro del mismo, que igual te facilitan la tarea

Comment: He actualizado la pregunta, no es nada de lo que dice en su comentario, ahora mismo quiero representar una información que tendré en el futuro, a nivel interno, no a nivel de UI

Comment: Si solo se trata de guardar datos en 3D, crea una clase dro llamada `Trio<T>` donde tengas que almacenar 3 datos del mismo tipo, esto representara tu vector 3D y luego puedes crear tus vectores de tipo Integer, BigDecimal o lo que consideres necesario para intercambiar datos.

Comment: Un modelo 3D es mucho mas que una lista de vertices; hay coordenadas uv y vectores de normales para la direccion de las caras. Lo mas universal que conozco son los ficheros Wavefront .obj. La mayoria de los programas 3D leen y escriben este formato. Existen librerias en java sin dependencias que permiten cargar en memoria este tipo de archivos.